# Filtrar um data frame por valores de uma coluna

Tags: r, dataframe

Estou com um data frame com valores de uma coluna sendo um ID de usuário, alguns dos valores dessa coluna estão com duas cópias ou mais, sendo a primeira linha com ID replicado a mais recente e as outras mais antigas.

Gostaria de um método que eu consiga criar um outro data frame com o primeiro dos valores replicados junto com os outros valores que já são singulares. O máximo que consegui foi filtrar os distintos com esse comando:

```
dados2 = dados[!duplicated(dados$ID),]
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Não percebo o que são *valores que já são singulares*, pode explicar melhor? Além disso, pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem certeza que a primeira linha com ID replicado é a mais recente, e você quer manter essa linha, o seu código já faz isso, mantem a primeira linha do ID repetido.

Pode verificar com esses dados e procedimento alternativo:

```
dados<-structure(list(ID = c(4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 
                                15, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 40
), COM = c(102.7408349, 46.42860925, 46.42860925, 193.9867874, 
           77.78158526, 77.78158526, 259.2226911, 142.9585464, 142.9585464, 
           338.2513753, 201.6268249, 201.6268249, 540.8096753, 230.0649675, 
           230.0649675, 621.6945295, 243.5781577, 356.2446836, 678.4896365, 
           303.6745224, 532.1778946, 731.7253377, 317.1877126, 621.6366503, 
           794.4532011, 353.1853056, 688.7228286)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:27)

dados$seq=1:nrow(dados) # inserir sequencia
# para cada ID único escolher a mais recente (min de sequencia)
dados2= dados[sapply(unique(dados$ID),function(z)min(dados$seq[dados$ID==z])),]
dados3= dados[!duplicated(dados$ID),]
all.equal(dados2,dados3)
#[1] TRUE
```